# На сервер не приходят данные переданные методом POST через AJAX (без jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, email, xmlhttprequest

Отправляю данные на сервер через AJAX в рамках одного домена, но сервер ничего не получает.

**js файл**

```
var data = {
      rating : result,
      message : message
    };

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/test.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

Отправка идёт по клику на элементе (не форма, не кнопка submit)

```
star[i].addEventListener('click', selectStar);
```

**php файл**

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

**$data оказывается пустой**

Интересно, что если подключаю jquery все работает

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/test.php',
   data: {data:data}
});
```

**Пробовал:**

- Искать в гугле и здесь. Все что нашёл - попробовал, не помогло.
- Убрать весь остальной js код — не помогло.
- Передавать на сервер не объект а строку — ничего не меняется.
- менять протоколы (http и https) и версию php на сервере (с 4 по 7) - без результатов.

Уже пару дней над этим сижу. Очень буду рад советам и помощи. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отправьте так:

```
var data = 'rating=' + encodeURIComponent(result) +
           '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/test.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.send(data);
```

И проверьте что пришло:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Здорово, в var_dump стало приходить array(2) { ["rating"]=> string(1) "5 ["message"]=> string(4) "test"} А как к этому обратиться? Просто $data = $_POST["data"]; и $rating = $data["rating"]; нечего не даёт.

Comment: @Alex, `$_POST["rating"]` и `$_POST["message"]`.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос решён! Как я понял, проблема был в способе передачи массива. Может быть подскажите как это называется, чтобы я в гугле поискал и почитал?

Comment: @Alex, в учебнике есть статья https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-forms

Comment: @Alex, и вот еще https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Answer (score 4):

Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow.

В варианте с `XMLHttpRequest` Вы отправляете

```
{"rating":123,"message":"aaa"},
```

а в коде с `$.ajax` - отправляете

```
{"data":{"rating":123,"message":"aaa"}}
```

Получайте значения на сервере вот так:

```
var data = {
  rating : result,
  message : message
};
...
request.send($.param(data));
...
$rating = $_POST["rating"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

или

```
var data = {
  data: {
    rating : result,
    message : message
  }
};
...
request.send($.param(data));
...
$data = $_POST["data"];
```

Comment: Igor, спасибо, что объяснили про объект и разницу с jquery!

Не ругайтесь :) но у меня ничего не получается - ничего не приходит на сервер: попробовал оба ваших варианта. Как писал выше, я даже попробовал отправлять на сервер не объект, а просто строку типа var data = 'hi', но  $data почему-то оказывается пустой. Меняю на jquery (т.е. только в js код добавляю эти 5 строк) всё окей. Ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @Alex, уберите из содержимого заголовка `;charset=UTF-8`.